# Accessing backbone object inside requireJS without defining it

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, dependencies

I use RequireJS with Backbone.js.

In index.html I link require.js and define entry point start.js:

```
<script src="/app/vendor/require.js" data-main="/app/start"></script>
```

In start.js I configure RequireJS to access Backbone library with its dependencies:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'vendor/jquery',
    underscore: 'vendor/underscore',
    backbone: 'vendor/backbone'
  },
});
```

To use Backbone module in this file I can define it as a dependency:

```
require(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
  console.log(Backbone);
});
```

But I define as dependancy child module which has Backbone as its dependancy

start.js:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'vendor/jquery',
    underscore: 'vendor/underscore',
    backbone: 'vendor/backbone'
  },
});

require(['child'], function (Child) {
  console.log(Backbone);
});
```

child.js:

```
define(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {});
```

Why I can access Backbone module in start.js without defining it? If I will use any other custom module I will receive error. This works only with Backbone module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `require` calls requires your `child` module, which requires `backbone`, so by the time `child` is loaded and the callback executes, the `backbone` module has been loaded. Now, let's see what this module does:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
    // Export global even in AMD case in case this script is loaded with
    // others that may still expect a global Backbone.
    root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);
  });
...
```

As you can see there, even if you load Backbone as an AMD module, it still exports into the global space the symbol `Backbone`. (The `root` variable is equivalent to `window` in a browser or `global` in Node.js.) This is why your code works.

For my own work, I'd write the call like this:

```
require(['backbone', 'child'], function (Backbone, Child) {
```

so as to avoid relying on the global symbol. Future versions of Backbone *could* cease to export the global symbol when they detect that they are loaded as an AMD module.